# Filling nulls with expression

Tags: sql, null, ifnull

```
ID | Seq | Status |
------+-------+-----+
 1 |  1  |   OK   |
 1 |  2  |  Fail  |
 1 |  3  |  NULL  |
 1 |  4  |  NULL  |
```

I have the data above that I am working with. I would like there to be no nulls in the status bar. Instead, if something has failed somewhere in the sequence, the status should be failed all the way to the end as can be seen below:

```
ID | Seq | Status |
------+-------+-----+
 1 |  1  |   OK   |
 1 |  2  |  Fail  |
 1 |  3  |  Fail  |
 1 |  4  |  Fail  |
```

I started with doing a simple lag, but that didn't work when failing early in the process. The later steps in the sequence would still be NULL.

```
SELECT ID 
,Seq
,CASE 
    WHEN STATUS IS NULL
    THEN LAG(STATUS, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
    ELSE STATUS
END AS STATUS
FROM table
```

Any ideas?

Comment: couldn't you just update your table at the end of your sequence so that all your NULLs are replaced by "Fail"?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ORDER BY Seq` in your `LAG` function?

Comment: what database server are you using ?